# AsteriskNow the http gui dies after a day

Tags: graphical-user-interface, asterisknow

I run an AsteriskNow! box for our phones. Everything works just fine except for the http console dies after about a day of up time. If I restart the server, everything comes up just fine. I am trying to find a way to not have to restart everytime I need access to the box with http.

I have done some research on the AsteriskNow! forums and I thought it was the "log-rotate bug", however this solution has since stopped working. http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?t=64400

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the actual bug, but it is probable that restarting just the apache server will get the service working again.  Not sure what distribution AsteriskNow runs under but there should be a start script in either /etc/init.d/ /etc/rc.d/ /usr/etc/init.d/ or /usr/etc/rc.d that can be used to restart the apache.  The command will look like  `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

Comment: yep, this is exactly what I wanted. Here is how I did it for those who follow me.

1. I ssh into AsteriskNow with putty

2. type "sudo /etc/init.d/gui-lighttpd restart"

3. type in my administrator password, everything works like it should. 

I don't like that it breaks, but at least I don't have to restart the entire server to make the http login page work. Thanks Catherine